# How could I have an Ubuntu public sever, and a security gateway for my private LAN, using only one public IP address?

Tags: networking, server, gateway

I've moved to a rural area with a small telecom company that has just started offering fiber.  They say I can get a fiber modem/gateway/router with Wi-Fi AP on a private LAN.  But if I get a static public IP, the same gateway can't be set up to provide both a public static IP, and a gateway to my LAN. (I don't believe it as AT&T did this for me in Atlanta)

So I have my server acting as the gateway, DNS and DHCP to my LAN.

I would much prefer to have the server just as a server, and use a dedicated device such as the Ubiquiti USG as the gateway. But how?

The telecom device is a Calix GigaSpear Blast u6x GS4227. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 on the server on Public IP at 64.179.x.x. The LAN is a mix of hardwired devices at 192.168.x.x backed by a wireless mesh network. Let me know if pictures will help and thanks!

Comment: A Google search suggests that this device is a combination fiber-modem and router. It's unclear why you cannot use the device as a mere modem and place your own router ("gateway") downstream with any features you want. It's also unclear how this question is relevant for AskUbuntu, since neither your modem nor your router run Ubuntu.

Comment: It is relevant because it involves an Ubuntu server and some knowledgeable people may suggest either a solution which involves the server, or a headless Ubuntu device that may  provide a solution. But I must apologize for not being clear as you do not seem to grasp the problem. When you say "It's unclear why you cannot use the device as a mere modem and place your own router ("gateway") downstream with any features you want", well that is exactly what I have done with an Ubuntu server. But that does not separate the public facing Ubuntu server from the gateway (NOT router) function.

Comment: I am also unclear about your response.  Did you have a suggestion or possible answer to my query?

Comment: To clarify: The Calix device performs the function of a gateway when used in the typical home internet service.  But when used as a modem to provide a static public IP, my ISP says that the gateway function is not available.  I.e., there is no NAT. No subnet. No dhcp, blah blah.  So I solved that by doing all those functions on my server.  But I would like to offload the server of this load. One option is the USG, but another is a R-PI or other SBC running Ubuntu.  Either way, I still have the issue of only one public IP.

Comment: Yes this is mostly a networking question, so if y'all feel the question itself is not germane, I will take it somewhere else where the audience might be more knowledgeable in this area.